# prevent bootstrap accordion from expanding beyond parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

first of all - I'm a total jQuery and javascript noob, so please bear that in mind during answering my question.

I have an accordion thingie on my webpage.
How do I prevent the accordion from expanding beyond parent div?

```
<div class="section" style="padding-top:30px; padding-bottom:30px; border-top:0; border-bottom:0; background:#FFF">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <h4 class="classic-title"><span>Accordion Style</span></h4>

                            <!-- Accordion -->
                            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">

                                    <!-- Start Accordion 1 -->
                                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                                        <div class="panel-heading">
                                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-1">
                                                    <i class="icon-down-open-1 control-icon"></i>
                                                    <i class="icon-laptop-1"></i>some text here
                                                </a>
                                            </h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="collapse-1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                                            <div class="panel-body">some text here</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><!-- End Accordion 1 -->
```

I didn't include the closing tags, but don't worry - everything is closed off properly.

I have 7 elements in the accordion - for this example's sake I included only one. When page loads for the first time, the first element is automatically open. That's ok. When I open the second element, the first one closes automatically. That too is intended and it's cool. What bothers me is, that every time I open a different element THE WHOLE BOTTOM OF THE PAGE INCLUDING FOOTER makes an ugly twitch upwards and down. It is how it's supposed to work for the elements inside the accordion thingie, but I would like the rest of the page to "remain calm" - not to move at all, when clicking different elements. The parent tag of the accordion should be the same size at all time.
Any ideas?
PS: I don't know if it's important to mention this, nevertheless - the page is a bootstrap responsive template.

Answer (score 0):

it is a normal behavior for the Bootstrap accordion's container. A way would be to lock the height of the accordion on the max height depending on the "bigger" accordion item.

http://jsfiddle.net/axvhcfob/1/

See the below script, it re-assesses the height every "expand" events and changes the container's height if bigger. You cannot do it on load because the collapsed items have -1px height.

```
$(function () {
    var maxHeight = 0;
    $('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
        calculateHeight();
    })

    function calculateHeight() {
        var currentHeight = 0;
        $(".panel-heading").each(function (key, value) {
            currentHeight+=$(value).innerHeight();
        });
        currentHeight+=$(".collapse.in").innerHeight();  
        console.log($(".collapse.in").innerHeight());
        if(currentHeight>maxHeight)
        {
            maxHeight=currentHeight;
           $(".container").height(maxHeight);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks guys, I'll give your answers a try and then I'll get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with jQuery UI Accordion:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  });
  </script>



<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
    ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
    amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
    odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
    purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
    velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In
    suscipit faucibus urna.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 3</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
    Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero
    ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis
    lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li>List item one</li>
      <li>List item two</li>
      <li>List item three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 4</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus
    et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
    faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia
    mauris vel est.
    </p>
    <p>
    Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus.
    Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
    inceptos himenaeos.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```